# Sharepoint list retriving and updating using VBA

Tags: vba, sharepoint

I'm new to this, but have been reading some answers earlier and see some experts have clarified many topics which are complex and so seeking help.

I'm trying update sharepoint list item using VBA and not able to find a way. It appears in some thread somebody mentioned that they had been able to do. If someone has already done so, can you share the simple code to retrive a sharepoint list item and as well update the list item.

I know how to use the list data using data connection inside Excel and there I get the complete list, but no idea how to get a particular item in the list's fields.

Would apppreciate immensely if a simple code can be shared to pull data from list to word/excel.

Thanks in advance
Satish

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft has now retired their SOAP API for Sharepoint. So, it's no longer supported. Now, Microsoft has implemented REST API calls. If you're still looking for alternatives to this, try working this out. NOTE - this is only meant to retrieve values from a Sharepoint list.

```
Set req = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
params = "owssvr.dll?Cmd=Display&ID=&XMLDATA=true&List=%7B<LISTID>%7D&View=%7B<VIEWID>%7D"
URL = "https://<SHAREPOINTSITE>/" & params
req.Open "GET", URL, False
req.Send
```

Comment: Something is off. Fiddler doesn't even register a *request* when I run this from MS VBA against my SharePoint.